# Disabling a minor mode in a specific buffer

Tags: customize, minor-mode, conditionals

Running spacemacs 0.200.13 on emacs 25.2.2 on Kubuntu 18.04.

I have globally enabled `golden-ratio-mode` (a minor mode). But I would like to disable it in a particular buffer, `*Org Agenda*` to be specific.

I do not want to disable it for ALL org-mode buffers but ONLY for this particular buffer.

How do I get this?

Answer (score 2):

You should be able to do what you want with something like:

```
(add-to-list 'golden-ratio-exclude-buffer-regexp "*Org Agenda*")
```

Comment: See also `M-x customize-group RET golden-ratio RET` for additional options.

Answer (score 0):

I'd try something like:

```
(require 'golden-ratio)
(golden-ratio-mode 1)
(add-hook 'org-agenda-hook (lambda () (golden-ratio-mode -1)))
```

But I'm not sure how will that look like, as `golden-ratio-mode` re-scales windows as they are being loaded and affects that way everything in the frame at that moment.

Comment: Thanks. As I understand, the hook is for all org-agenda buffers. Is there a way to apply the hook based on the name of the buffer?

Comment: when you disable `golden-ratio` with `M-x golden-ratio-mode` it disables it globally, unlike a minor mode that affects only its buffer.